# How to use Resharper to localize XAML strings

Tags: xaml, localization, resharper-5.0

I use Reshaper 5.1.1 to extract strings to resource files in my Silverlight app. I want to be able to extract strings in my XAML (like Content or Text properties) - but the Move option under Resharper is never enabled when I am viewing XAML. It does not identify possible text strings for extraction.

I have done extensive searching but can't seem to find much about R# and localizing XAML files. Is it possible, and how can I enable it? (I checked all my settings and there's nothing about XAML and resources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to R# support forums](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5280157#5280157), XAML string extraction is only possible in WPF, not Silverlight! This is very annoying... there is another tool called Resource Refactor (or similar) on CodePlex which does the job until R# support SL.

Comment: Apparently you can do it now in build EAP 2155 with Resharper